# How to get the old volume control back in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 changed the panes that open from the notification area. Is it possible to get the old volume control back when clicking the sound icon in the system tray?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bring back the one used in Windows 8 with a registry edit.

1. Open the following Registry key, if MTCUVC doesn't exist create it:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\MTCUVC
2. Create a new 32-bit DWORD value named EnableMtcUvc with a value of 0.

This should work instantly. If not, you can try logging in and out or restarting.